# Dual monitor, Independent workspace

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xfce, workspaces

I searched this for a while but I cannot find a solution.

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 and Xfce 4.12.

When I plug a second monitor my workspace is expanded into the two monitors (this is the default behaviour). What I want instead is to display a different workspace in the second monitor (could be the rightmost workspace or any fixed workspace, both options would work fine for me).

Is this possible with Xfce or should I install another desktop environment?

Thanks in advance.